# Error The Write timed out

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?
Code is in C#...
It gives me error "The Write timed out", but I set up WriteTimeout...

I want write some data to serial port.
I use .NET FRAMEWORK 3.5

```
}
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600, System.IO.Por­ts.Parity.None, 8,    System.IO.Por­ts.StopBits.O­ne);

sp.WriteTimeout = 500;
sp.Open();


try
{
sp.Write("Hello");
}
catch (TimeoutException) { Console.Write­Line("Error"); }

sp.Close();

Console.ReadKey();
}
```

thanks

Comment: Is this C#? If so, add the tag. Is this all the code? Do you have a COM6 serial port?

Comment: Yes,this is C# and yes I have COM6 Iam using Virtual Serial Port

Comment: And is something listening at COM6 ?

Comment: No,I have bridge COM6<-->COM7.

Comment: Unlike real serial port, virtual bridge may lock a writer, if anyone doesn't read connected port. Start the program which reads COM7, and then execute this program.